# Spring mvc Swagger UI endpoint for two different URL pattern

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller, swagger

I have two different url patterns one which starts with /api and second which starts with /svc. So, my question here is can we have two different swagger endpoint urls for these both API documentation using Swagger ?

I am using Spring MVC and Swagger for documentation purpose. Any hint please ? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you able to figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

```
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
public class SwaggerConfig {

 @Bean
    public Docket api() { 
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)  
          .select()                                  
          .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())              
          .paths(PathSelectors.any())                          
          .build();                                           
    }
}
```

This has to help you.
The code:

```
apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
```

will select all the apis from your controllers.

Comment: No, i want two different swagger documentation url like /api/swagger-ui.html and /svc/swagger-ui.html